# Finding DNA from Amino Acid sequence problem

Tags: dna, genetics, homework

[image]

My attempt: First I took the single letter AA codes and made them amino acids.  So, the first one is Trp which is 5'-UGG-3'.   From this I got the DNA sequence 3'-CCA-5'.  However, the correct answer (shown in red) doesn't have this sequence.  What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach to translate the AA sequence, codon by codon, was correct. This was a bit of a trick question because to recognize it, you had to read the sequence backwards.

UGG-CAA-GGT-CAC etc is read directly off of the 3'->5' strand of the circled answer, reading from right to left.

The bottom left is a red herring because it starts with a start codon, ATG, but reading beyond the start codon, the sequence wouldn't match.